# python syntax datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Why is the date output formats different between these two codes? One is the datetime object, the other one seems to be a string (I prefer the string look alike format). What am I missing?

```
def generator():

    i=0
    while (i<50000):
        yield random.randint(-1, 1), datetime.datetime.now()
        i=i+1

mynumber = 100

for random_number, current_time in generator():
    mynumber += random_number  

print mynumber,",", current_time
```

Output:

```
>>> 100 , 2013-04-04 09:16:55.730000
101 , 2013-04-04 09:16:55.746000
```

Second example:

```
def test(timestamp,interval = 1*60):
    xt = datetime.datetime(2013, 4,4)
    #dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    dt=timestamp
    delta_second =(dt - xt).seconds
    normalize_second = (delta_second / interval) * interval
    newtime = xt + timedelta(seconds=normalize_second)
    print (dt,newtime)

test(datetime.datetime.now())
```

```
>>> (datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 9, 21, 12, 386000), datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 9, 21))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are printing *different things*. In the first example you print the datetime *directly*, so `print` converts it to `str()`.

In the second example you print a *tuple*, and tuples always are printed with the contents as `repr()` instead:

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print now
2013-04-04 10:28:10.029566
>>> print (now,)  # tuple
(datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 10, 28, 10, 29566),)
>>> print repr(now)
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 10, 28, 10, 29566)
```

In both cases you are still printing a `datetime` object.

Comment: get it now, did not know yet the differences with the print(), thanks.

Comment: @matel: I think you got confused with Python 3, where `print()` is now a function. You can get the same behaviour in Python 2 by adding `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your module.